# what is the problem of this mysql query?

Tags: mysql, date-format

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table_temp
WHERE
    install_date < NOW()
AND install_date > DATE_FORMAT(2011 - 06 - 16, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem resides on theis line:

```
install_date > DATE_FORMAT(2011 - 06 - 16, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

The 1st variable should be a string of a date

For example:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2007-10-04 22:23:00', '%H:%i:%s');
```

Or in your case:

```
install_date > DATE_FORMAT('2011 - 06 - 16', "%Y-%m-%d")
```

[**See MySQL DOC**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 1):

The value 2011 - 06 - 16 needs to be wrapped up in quotes